# You Can't Signin with Personal Account. Use Company Account When integrated Outlook calendar with .net Application

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have integrated Microsoft Outlook Calendars using graph.microsoft.com api. When a user tries to get events using his outlook account, it gives error to signin with work/organization account.
I can not figure out this problem. Please help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Are you talking about API endpoint? 
I am using c#.

Comment: Is it a programming question? I'd suggest posting non-porramming questions to the superuser.com web site instead.